# Is there a way to display and check the remaining time of the session at any point in the script?

Tags: php, session

Where is the validity period of the session extended at what point in the script?

- `read` method？

  ```
  class DatabaseSession implements SessionHandlerInterface
  {
    public function read($sess_id)
    { 
      here？
  ```
- When accessing `$_SESSION`?

  ```
  if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  ```

I want to check the remaining time until the session expires.

Comment: When you run the `session_start()`

Comment: try to attach a new `$_SESSION` variable and store the current timestamp in it.

Comment: Will the expiration date be extended for the duration of the session?

Comment: No, you can't by default. Session expiry is always updated to the amount of your `session.cache_expire` when you call `session_start()`. But you can trick it. And, what's the your purpose of getting your session validity period?

Comment: It is simply to understand session behavior. I was misunderstanding. If (! Isset ($ _ SESSION)) {
   session_start ();
}, In this case,Is not the extension process during the session period, but ,it will the session expiration extension be restarted after the session is over?